# dovecot error Unknown setting: unix_listener

Tags: postfix, dovecot, imap

I'm trying to enable postfix auth. I'm editing the this section from `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`

```
# Postfix smtp-auth
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
}
```

But after I restart dovecot I get this error:

```
Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf line 88: Unknown setting: unix_listener
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Comment: Make sure to put this `unix_listener` block in a `service auth { ... }` block.

Answer (score 8):

You should put this `unix_listener` block inside a `service auth` block, like so :

```
service auth {
    unix_listener /some/path { ... }
}
```